# Finding the Internal Voltage and Resistance of a Battery given the behavior of the circuit it's part of

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am tasked with finding the internal resistance and voltage of a battery. I am given the following:

> A simple circuit consists of a real battery and a resistor in series. When the resistor's resistance is 35-Ohms, a voltmeter reads 9V. The resistor is then swapped out for one with a resistance of 14-Ohms and the voltmeter reads 8.1V

I'm not sure how I can use this information to find the internal resistance and voltage of the battery.

Since I have values for two situations and two unknowns I think I need to relate the values in such a way that I have two equations and can then solve for the needed values. I tried using the loop rule and some of the fundamental formulas for current/resistance etc. to set up a system of equations since that's the only method I've seen that seems potentially useful but it doesn't line up correctly.

Any tips/hints?

Comment: Make a plot of voltage as a function of current.

Answer (score 1):

Smells of homework. But a real battery is a ideal battery (of voltage *V*) and a resistor, *R*. The question says that you apply a load of 35 $\Omega$ (which would be in series with *R*) and measure 9 V across it.  Then you apply a load of 14 $\Omega$ and the voltage is now 8.1 V  What are the values of *V* & *R*?

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to figure out. I can't figure out how to relate the variables to the knows in such a way that I can solve for the former.

Comment: Do the plot as @Pieter says.  Fit a line. (or derive the equation) What's the voltage when the current is zero?  That's your *V*. Using this *V* and the information in either of the results, calculate *R*.